# Permission denied for relation table outbox

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sms-gateway, sql-grant, gammu

i want to instal gammu-smsd but i got error

```
Thu 2014/11/20 06:04:17 gammu-smsd[31457]: Error: ERROR:  permission denied for                             relation outbox  
Thu 2014/11/20 06:04:17 gammu-smsd[31457]: SQL failure: 2
Thu 2014/11/20 06:04:17 gammu-smsd[31457]: Table outbox not found, disconnecting                            !
Thu 2014/11/20 06:04:17 gammu-smsd[31457]: Initialisation failed, stopping Gammu                             smsd: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
```

i have user is smsd and database name is smsd with owner smsd.

i try running:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO smsd;
```

but its not working,

can you help me solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: If `outbox` is a table, not a sequence, then granting to sequences won't do any good. Perhaps you should grant to `ALL TABLES` instead, or just `GRANT ALL ON outbox TO smsd` ?

Comment: its alraedy solved. thanks

Comment: how about update gammu in version 1.33.90?